# PL SQL Procedure Exercise

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I'm not really sure how to approach this question.. I understand the basic syntax of writing a procedure. This is an exercise for a beginner database class (which seems to be at a level way above beginner)

Create a procedure to place a purchase order for a specified date based on data in the inventory report table.

Name the procedure `placeorder` [procedure name is important].

The procedure should take one parameter: `inputDate` (use the datatype of the `PODate` column in `PURCHASEORDERS`). The input date format accepted should be: `'DD-MON-YYYY'`, e.g., 01-JAN-2017.

For each raw material in the Inventory Report table (where: ReportDate matches inputDate), make a separate entry in the `PURCHASEORDERS` table for a next-day delivery order and a same-day delivery order (each raw material may generate up to 2 inserts).

- Corresponding order type should be either next_day or same_day
- Only make an entry (insertion) in `PURCHASEORDERS` if needed, i.e., if
  an entry exists for a raw material and report date combination in the
  Inventory Report table. If the Inventory Report for a day (e.g.,
  30-NOV-2017) has a 0 value for the ordersameday attribute, it means
  no same_day order is needed.

If no order is needed for the provided input date (i.e., no order at all across ALL raw materials), raise an application error with a message: “no order needed” (see Triggers and Procedures tutorial on D2L for an example of how to raise this error). You can use any suitable error-number.  Your procedure should leave the “Price” (for the purchase order) empty (i.e., it can remain null). Assume it’ll be populated later.

Thanks!

Comment: I know it should probably go:

     `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE placeorder;`
     DECLARE
     c_inputdate PURCHASEORDERS.PODATE%TYPE;
     CURSOR C1 IS 
     <select statement for data needed>`

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of examples how to create a procedure. Here a small one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ProcName (paraName IN VARCHAR2)
AS
    myStringVariable   VARCHAR2 (4000);
    myDateVariable     DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT orderDateAsString
      INTO myStringVariable
      FROM orders
     WHERE orderId = paraName;

    myDateVariable := TO_DATE (myStringVariable, 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI:SS'); -- '13.03.2018 23:59:59'
    dbms_output.put_line('My date: ' || myStringVariable);
END;
```

And some example-code, to call the procedure:

```
begin
    ProcName('1234');
end;
```

But you should look at your exercise first and think about you tasks. I think, this is what you got to do:

1. Create a Table.
2. Create Insert-Statements for the table
3. Create some PL/SQL-code which performs the insert with conditions.
4. move the PL/SQL-code to a procedure.
5. Call the procedure with a PL/SQL-block.

#### Explaination for you edits

You should build your code step-by-step if. You got multiple errors.

6. Check you Cursor. The Select-statement is not valid.

   - You wrote two selects.
   - You do not use new_inputdate. Why did you define it and what should it do?
   - Run you SELECT-statement alone without your code. if you like your data you can put it in an cursor.

Example with your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE placeorder (inputDate IN DATE)
AS
    -- new_inputDate    PURCHASEORDERS.PODate%TYPE; --you don't use this one
    new_orderType    PURCHASEORDERS.ORDERTYPE%TYPE;
    c_orderSameDay   INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERSAMEDAY%TYPE;
    c_orderNextDay   INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERNEXTDAY%TYPE;

    -- you mixed up your cursors. seems like you didn't try the select-statement alone.. 
    CURSOR C2
    IS
        SELECT ir.itemId, ir.ORDERSAMEDAY, ir.ORDERNEXTDAY
          FROM INVENTORYREPORT
         WHERE ir.REPORTDATE = inputDate;

BEGIN
    OPEN C2;
    WHILE C2%FOUND
    LOOP
        FETCH C2 INTO new_orderType, c_orderSameDay, c_orderNextDay;
            NULL; -- Do something
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C2;
END;
/
```

7. Think about what you want to do in the loop. Build a small skript with the variables and think about what it should do:

Example-Skript of you Loop-content:

```
DECLARE
    -- new_inputDate    PURCHASEORDERS.PODate%TYPE; --you don't use this one
    new_orderType    NUMBER := 0;
    c_orderSameDay   NUMBER := 1;
    c_orderNextDay   NUMBER := 2;
BEGIN

    -- this is what you're doing in you loop.

    IF c_orderSameDay > 0 -- check if c_orderSameDay is greater than 0? In Oracle you use 'NULL' as empty value. Perhaps it should be 'c_orderSameDay IS NOT NULL'
    THEN
        INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType) -- you perform your insert.
             VALUES (orderSameDay);
    ELSE
        RAISE; -- you raise an exception? this means c_orderSameDay has alsway to be set.
    END IF;

    IF c_orderNextDay > 0
    THEN
        INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType)
             VALUES (orderNextDay);
    ELSE
        RAISE; -- you raise an exception? this means c_orderNextDay has alsway to be set.
    END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is what i've written so far.. @kara

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE placeorder (inputDate in DATE)
AS

new_inputDate PURCHASEORDERS.PODate%TYPE;
new_orderType PURCHASEORDERS.ORDERTYPE%TYPE;
c_orderSameDay INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERSAMEDAY%TYPE;
c_orderNextDay INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERNEXTDAY%TYPE;

CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT REPORTDATE INTO inputDate FROM dual;
SELECT ir.itemId, ir.ORDERSAMEDAY, ir.ORDERNEXTDAY FROM INVENTORYREPORT 
WHERE 
ir.REPORTDATE = inputDate;

BEGIN
OPEN C1;
WHILE C1%FOUND LOOP
FETCH C1 INTO new_inputDate, new_orderType, c_orderSameDay, c_orderNextDay;

IF c_orderSameDay > 0
THEN INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType) VALUES (orderSameDay);
ELSE <application error>;
END IF;

IF c_orderNextDay > 0
THEN INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType) VALUES (orderNextDay);
ELSE <application error>;
END IF;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;

END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

@kara I added to the if statements but still getting a couple errors when trying to compile the procedure.  It this doing what it's supposed to be doing?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE placeorder (inputDate in DATE)
AS

new_inputDate PURCHASEORDERS.PODate%TYPE;
new_orderType PURCHASEORDERS.ORDERTYPE%TYPE;
c_orderSameDay INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERSAMEDAY%TYPE;
c_orderNextDay INVENTORYREPORT.ORDERNEXTDAY%TYPE;

CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT REPORTDATE INTO inputDate FROM dual;
SELECT ir.itemId, ir.ORDERSAMEDAY, ir.ORDERNEXTDAY FROM INVENTORYREPORT 
WHERE 
ir.REPORTDATE = inputDate;

BEGIN
OPEN C1;
WHILE C1%FOUND LOOP
FETCH C1 INTO new_inputDate, new_orderType, c_orderSameDay, c_orderNextDay;

IF c_orderSameDay > 0
THEN INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType) VALUES (orderSameDay);
ELSE INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType) VALUES ('no order needed');
END IF;

IF c_orderNextDay > 0
THEN INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType) VALUES (orderNextDay);
ELSE INSERT INTO PURCHASEORDERS (new_orderType) VALUES ('no order needed');
END IF;
FETCH C1 INTO new_inputDate, new_orderType, c_orderSameDay, c_orderNextDay;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE C1;
COMMIT;
END placeorder;
/
```